# what the technology to create a real time application?

Tags: sockets, real-time, server-push

i wanna to know what the technology must i  do when i want to create an application like:

1. real time application ?
2. multiplayer in game ?

sometimes i'm read this article [keep alive](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Keepalive).
what is that support in socket TCP ?, i'm already read server push but is many example work under HTTP, how about in TCP like create  a socket TCPServer and TCPClient.

Comment: Start small. Write a (real-time, duh) chat application first. It'll give you an idea for how to go about multiplayer, real-time games

Comment: yes i'm ready write chat application using nodejs + socket.io their implement in web socket , how about i'm not use browser example like game in unity..?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't just one "go-to" technology for making real-time / multiplayer gaming applications.  You have to understand a multitude of different programming realms like graphics manipulation, threading, networking(TCP,etc).  I would say it would be good for you to pick up a book on game development and design at your local library, bookstore or on the web.  You also want to decide where and how you want to run the game.  If you are going for a desktop application you are probably going to want to use a language like Java or C++/C#.  For web applications Java and Flash are historically the way to go, and there is even a growing case for games written primarily in javascript (presumably with a .NET/PHP back-end).

If you want to jump right in you might try a framework like [Unity](http://unity3d.com/) which I believe is based on Microsoft's .NET framework.  This tool has a lot of things built into it which would help you get started.

I know that is not a lot of specific information but hopefully it points you in the right direction.

Comment: thans for your answer can you suggestme what the book to i'm read about my problem..?

Comment: I do not have any specific books in mind.  You would need to use a search engine or just browse around.  There are always new books on all kinds of programming, from gaming to web development.